# Weird <section> Behaviour in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working with the Twitter Bootstrap on a mini project. I am using 's with it and there is a bit of weird behaviour. I have jQuery which allows me to create new tabs when a button is clicked. The new tab is made active and contains a form. This form displaces the title of the  below and I can't find out why. Can anyone help?

Code Snippets:

```
<section id="builder">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>App Builder. <small>Create your app.</small></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="span7">
    <!-- ===== App Title ===== -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="appTitle">App Title</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="appTitle">
        <p class="help-block">Enter the title for your app. It will appear at the top of your app.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ===== App Subtitle ===== -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="appSubtitle">App Subtitle</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="appSubtitle">
        <p class="help-block">Enter the subtitle for your app. It will appear below the title.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ===== App Theme ===== -->
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="appTheme">App Theme</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select id="appTheme">
          <option>Dark</option>
          <option>Light</option>
        </select>
        <p class="help-block">Select the theme for your app. You can preview your theme on the right.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ===== App Pages ===== -->
    <p>App Pages</p>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabHeaders">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="createTab"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add Page</a></li>
      <!-- Tabs (Created by Javascript) -->
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
      <!-- Tab Content (Created by Javascript) -->
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="iphonebackground">
      <div class="screenbackground"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="preview">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Preview your App. <small>See your app in it's full glory before you download it.</small></h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Before adding a new tab:
[image: Before Adding New Tab]

After adding a new tab:
[image: After Adding New Tab]

Comment: create a jsfiddle for it or post your jquery code.

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything I did not think that the jQuery was relevant but if you want it, it is at http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/eYePA/

Comment: added inline styling to your section element. Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/eYePA/23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the text is being floated around the new tab. Try using `clear:left;` in the CSS for that text to see if it correctly drops back below the tab.

Comment: Which text are you talking about?

Comment: Added `clear:left;` to the CSS for `<section>` and it works now.

Comment: I meant the `<section>` containing the text, sorry for not being more specific! Glad that sorted it.